# How to support transaction/failover on jms?

Tags: java, transactions, jms, failover

At back end i want the atomic transactions which means that

```
try{
get database connection

update employee record;
update department record;
produces messages 1 on queue1
produces messages 2 on queue2
// some exception occured
}
finally{
connection.rollback();
// how to roll back the messages from queue
}
```

similarily if message broker is down how will i ensure , message is deilvered once it is up.

I am using ActiveMQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a JmsSession to send the messages, you can do `jmsSession.commit()` and `jmsSession.rollback()` to complete the jms transaction.

If you want the messages to be persistent, i.e. they can be delivered after jms server crash, you can set the delivery mode of the message to be persistent: `jmsMessageProducer.send(msg, DeliveryMode.PERSITENT)`

See this for details:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Session.html

Comment: but how will i synch database and jms transactions?

Comment: You will have to use distributed transactions using JTA, that's normally provide by the JEE container, e.g. JBoss, what container are you using?

Comment: i am using tomcat.Basically what i want if there is errorn db transaction, rollback jms transaction also/ Similarly if there is exception in jms transaction, rollback db transaction

Comment: You have 2 options: use container managed transaction with JTA (Tomcat doesn't provide it) or handle the transaction yourself, i.e. try/catch if no errors commit both JDBC/JPA and commit the JMS session, otherwise rollback both. If you need absolute guarantee of consistency you may need a proper distributed transaction manager (JTA) which uses the two-phase-commit http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14012/jta.htm

Comment: i think EJB provides this transaction management off the shelve. i am not saying i will use ejb here but just wanted to know